# how to add data to a table cell without affecting height of other cells

Tags: html, css

I have to add data to table cells dynamically. But when I add data to one cell, the height of all the other cells also increases. So, is there any way that the height of only that cell where data is added increases, rest remain same.

Also is there any way to insert only table cells beneath certain cells in a row without adding a new row?

Comment: Sounds like you're using tables for non-tabular data. Quit doing that.

Comment: Sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341).  What are you REALLY trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have json data and i need to extract from it and display the fields in tabular form. Some of the fields contains nested elements, so I have to display the nested elements in the same cell or a different cell beneath the cell in order to create a hierarchy look.

Comment: can you do Rowspan where required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

embed the content in each cell within a DIV and enable overflow:auto on that div, so that a scroll bar appears if the height exceeds the maximum permitted.

Answer (score 1):

`<table><tr><td height="50"> Hello World!!</td></tr></table>`

Put the height inside the td tag

Comment: Does this ensure the maxHeight though, it ensure the minHeight.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental problem... tables are grids. You can merge cells (col/rowspan) but a line is always a line - which is to say you can't make a cell a different height to its neighbours by definition.

If you're trying to show data in a hierarchical way, use a hierarchical structure like `<ul>`/`<li>` and style it as appropriate (margins, etc...). If you need block elements, have each `<li>` wrap a `<div>`